# Async function returns false but should return true

Tags: c#, function, asynchronous, boolean

I have a problem with a function that returns: false.

The problem is that the: return success runs Before the actual: sucess = true is hit since it is an Async function.

How can this function return true as it do succeed?

```
public bool onefunction(ChromiumWebBrowser browser) {
  bool success = false;
  browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync("someinfo").ContinueWith(t => {
    if (t.IsFaulted == false) {
      var response = t.Result;
      if (response.Success) {
        success = true;
      }
    }
  });

  //It returns false because this code runs before: "success = true"
  return success;
}
```

---

Comment: Thanks Nick, it is the language C#

Comment: You can't test the success until the function is finished.  Since your default is set to FALSE you are getting FALSE because you are checking the status before it finishes.

Comment: @jdweng yes that is true that is the problem I have. I don't know in what way I can do this?

Comment: You need to go "async all the way" and await `EvaluateScriptAsync`.

Comment: using `await` before `browser.GetMainFrame()....`.

Comment: When ever you use an ASYNC method you must have a way of determining when it is finished.  You could add another variable boolean FINISHED and set when method returns.  Or have a enumeration with three states : processing, true, false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Async all the way"-Approach:

```
public async Task<bool> onefunction(ChromiumWebBrowser browser) {
  bool success = false;
  try
  {
      var response = await browser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync("someinfo");
      succes = response.Success;
  }
  catch( Exception ex )
  {
      // TODO: Write Errorlog
  }

  return success;
}
```

Mind: This will mean that you need to change the calling code, too. If you cannot do that, please advise. We'll find a solution for that case.

Comment: This is interesting but I get this error: "Cannot simplicitly convert type "CefSharp.JavascriptResponse" to 'bool'"

Comment: I edited my initial version. Did you check the diff? I'll make it a little clearer in a sec.

Comment: Yes now the error dissapeard. I am not sure how to change the calling code for this either I am afraid. How do I call this "onefunction" to check the bool status?

Comment: That's the pain with "async all the way" - it needs to be "all the way". So that would be `bool success = await onefunction(browser);`

Comment: Yes I am a bit bad when it comes to await/async :) I do get another error so its almost right now I think: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<bool>'

Comment: Yes, that's true. So, if you cannot do that, have a look at this article: https://www.ryadel.com/en/asyncutil-c-helper-class-async-method-sync-result-wait/ and consider if it is ok in your setup to go "sync over async". But I'd only recommend to use that as last resort. If you have the chance to switch to async up until the highest caller, I'd do so.

Comment: Yes I have looked at the documenation before and they do not advice to use sync methods for this so I should stay async then.

Comment: I'd also recommend [Stephen Cleary's blog on that topic](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). It was really an enlightening read to me and I frequently go back to refresh my memory - see also: "[There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)" and "[Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)"

Comment: Thanks Fildor I will have a look at that. But for the: bool success = await onefunction(browser); I get the error: "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<bool>'"

Comment: So, I guess it is a bool function. Something like `bool callerFunc( someParam ){...`. You need to change that to `async Task<bool> callerFuncAsync( someParam ){...`. Which in turn then would be called with await, so that caller needs to be async and so on and so on. Hopefully you end up in a SDK-Called hook that can be async.

Comment: Sorry, I think I made a mistake. This seems to work: bool success = await onefunction(browser);